# QMediaPlayer can't pause at chosen timeframe

Tags: c++, qt, media-player

I am having issue of not being able to call out for pause or stop while doing it from script that checks position

This slot is connected to the slot from QMediaPlayer

```
void VideoPlayer::positionChanged(qint64 position)
{
    if(position>=3000)
    {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

in this slot the position is compared and after 3 seconds should pause the video
but instead it crashes application, i can pasue using buttons that have separate slot that issue same command `mediaPlayer.pause();`

when I turn on the debugger it points me to :

> 0x6665b67b  <+0x00bb>         int     3 in Qt5Cored!qt_message_fatal
>   [c:\users\qt\work\qt\qtbase\src\corelib\global\qlogging.cpp @ 1667]:

Anyone have a solution?

Could be any way just to pause the movie at chosen time

Comment: Can you include the error message printed in the console?

Comment: i have exception code: 0xc0000005; read access violation at : 0x0 flags=0x0, while i don't know why its read access violation cause i can do other actions like move position or read the current value

other than that i don't get any erro in console if i run it in not debug mode app just crashes without an error message